# What does ON mean in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

In this sentence from Animal Farm by George Orwell:

> There were only four dissentients, the three dogs and the cat, who was afterwards discovered to have voted **on** both sides.

What does "on" mean?

I can't seem to find a proper explanation in dictionaries.

Comment: What is puzzling you? _On_ is a preposition commonly used with _side_. It's true that we usually speak of voting _for_ a candidate, but this seems to be a vote for or against an idea rather than an election.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I know what _vote on_ means. I'm trying to figure out the logic behind it. _On_ might mean _in the direction of_ or _directed against or toward_ because of the word _side_, or it may mean _having as the object or the goal of action, thought, desire, etc._. or none of them. I'm just not sure.

Comment: 'Placed' a vote on each side of the debate (imagining the two parties sitting on either side of the house, as in Parliament) - or that's how I understand it.

Comment: @preachers Do you want to know the meaning of "on", or do you want someone to select the closest dictionary definition for you? These are not the same thing, and you seem to already know what it means. It's often the case that a dictionary will not capture every usage of a word, or that multiple usages are subsumed in one definition, but with an example sentence that only shows one of those usages

Comment: @gotube I want someone to select the closest dictionary definition for me. Because dictionaries are the most reliable resource for us ESL learners, at least for me. It's not feasible to ask questions whenever I come across a problem. I have to rely on dictionaries. Those little words like "on, of, get, go, etc." in English, however, have way too many senses. I can't figure it out for myself sometimes, hence the question.

Comment: @preachers I checked Merriam-Webster, and found no definition that matched this usage. If they had one, it would likely be identical to their [definition 5.a.2 of ***for***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for), which reads: "*in favor of*". As an English learner, finding an accurate definition for a usage of *content* word like "bridge" or "fly" is quite useful. But finding a definition for a function word like "on" is barely important at all, especially if you already understand the meaning in context.

Comment: @gotube I find it very useful to figure out the inner logic of those function word. Because they are everywhere! They combine with other verb to form an unique sense, the number of this kind of verbal phrase are huge! It's way too difficult to remember all these rather than to figure out the meaning of these little words in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

**vote on**

You vote **on** a proposal/bill/decision. There are two sides: the one side is **for** it, and the other one is **against** it. These four animals voted twice, on both sides.

> Both chambers plan **to vote on that policy** before January 15th.
>
> He faces **a vote on his future** at an annual meeting next week.
>
> The committee **voted on the proposal**, and accepted it unanimously.
>
> Now that we've heard all the arguments for and against the proposal, **shall we vote on it?**

Similarly, you decide **on** a matter, you express an option **on** a subject. In this sense, *on* means [**dealing with the subject of; about; concerning** (15)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Etymology_1).

**on the side**

Speaking metaphorically, voting draws a line between the supporters and the opposers. When you vote, you position yourself **on one side** of that line. In this sense, on means ["expressing figurative placement or attachment (3)"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Preposition) and is derived from its main physical meaning ["positioned at or resting against the outer surface of; attached to (2)"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on#Preposition).

Comment: I know _vote on_ may be just a fixed phrase, I just want an authoritative explanation from dictionary to make sure the logic behind it. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I disagree with your interpretation that it means "concerned with or relating to*: for that meaning, the sentence would have to be something like "There were only four dissentients, the three dogs and the cat, who was afterwards discovered to have voted **the matter**". It's actually the same meaning as in the sentence "Whose side are you on?".

Comment: @JavaLatte In Oxford dictionary, the example of "Whose side are you on?" is under the article of "used to show that somebody **belongs to** a group or an organization", which does not suit the sentence in question very well, doesn't it?

Comment: @preachers the vote in Animal farm is about whether or not wild animals like rats are comrades. One group/side thinks that they are comrades, and another group/side thinks that they are not. The dogs **belong to** one group and nearly all of the other animals **belong to** the other group. The cat has divided loyalties, and votes twice- once on the comrades side, and once on the not-comrades side- "on both sides".